# what is the solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

Consider the problem $u_t=u_{xx}, 0<x<\infty, t>0$ with the initial and boundary data given by $u(x,0)=f(x), x>0$ and $u(0,t)=g(t),\ t>0$. The solution for the above problem is given by $u(x,t)=\int_0^{\infty} G(x,\xi,t)f(\xi)d\xi -2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\partial K}{\partial x}(x,t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau$, where $K(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} exp\{-\frac{x^2}{4t}\}$ and $G(x,\xi,t) = K(x-\xi,t)-K(x+\xi,t)$.

What is the corresponding solution if the boundary data is given by $u_x(0,t)+\alpha(t)u(0,t)=g(t),\ t>0$.

Comment: I found out the solution, provided $\alpha(t)$ is constant. Use the transformation $v(x,t)=u_{x}(x,t)+\alpha u(x,t)$, then the problem reduces to dirichlet boundary condition. We know the solution for the equation $v(x,t)=u_{x}(x,t)+\alpha u(x,t)$. So, we can get back out $u(x,t)$